# When I try to multiply -1 with the elements of an array, I get the answer 0. I do not understand why

Tags: matlab, product

// final(i)=-1*A2(i);
This is where i am facing problem.
although A2 is not 0 at any iteration, still i get 0 in the final.
these are just ten values of d, just to give an idea what type of values i am dealing with.

```
d=[63820
   63594
   63382
   63123
   62921
   62712
   62536
   62350
   62129
   61914
   61668];

d=bin2dec(b);
a=bitget(d,16);
for i=1:10
    if (a(i)==1)  
        C1(i)=bitcmp(uint16(d(i)));
        A1(i)=C1(i)+1;
        A2=A1';
        final(i)=-1*A2(i);
    else  
        final(i)=d(i);
    end
end
```

i am multiplying -1 in another portion of the code and it is not giving any problem. kindly give your suggestions.

Comment: I would suggest you edit your question and format your code somewhat to make it easier to read.

Comment: Um. I edited your question so that the code was somewhat readable. You seem to have reverted the formatting for some reason.

Comment: yeah i just did, kindly have a look at it

Comment: What is going on here: `d=bin2dec(b);`? What happens with `d` and where is `b` defined?

Comment: i have shared a portion of the code. b is the binary form of d.i need to convert the binary to signed decimal. in d there are both positive and negative values, so i have taken the 2's complement of negative binary only and then convert it back to signed decimal. the problem only lies in line 8, it gives 0 when i multiply -1 with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that you cannot mix signed and unsigned arithemetics with integers. Not directly anyway. You have to tell specifically what you want. The line you mention gives zero because you multiply a `uint16` representation with `(-1)` which is by default recast from `double` to `uint16`, which truncates to zero (`0`). Use `int16` instead.

I have made a more clean version of your code using some better variables names (though some might disagree). I find it useful to use the mathematically intended "type" as a prefix on variables names (matrix, vector, etc.). You should also get in the habit of preallocating your data, even if the datastructures are quite small. I bet the MATLAB editor is likely screaming at you with annoying warnings in the right margin? :)

The `final` vector (an `int16` vector) should now contain the two's complement (negative) values if the 16th bit is set in the values of `vec_d`. Also not sure what `A2` was for, so I removed it.

```
% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
vec_d = [
   63820
   63594
   63382
   63123
   62921
   62712
   62536
   62350
   62129
   61914
   61668
];
vec_d = uint16(vec_d);

% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
% extract 16th bit:
vec_a = bitget(vec_d, 16);

% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
% preallocate other datastructures:
vec_C1 = zeros(size(vec_a), 'uint16');
vec_A1 = zeros(size(vec_a), 'uint16');
vec_final = zeros(size(vec_a), 'int16');

% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
for num_k = 1:numel(vec_a)
    if (vec_a(num_k) == 1)  
        vec_C1(num_k) = bitcmp(uint16(vec_d(num_k)));
        vec_A1(num_k) = vec_C1(num_k) + 1;
        vec_final(num_k) = (-1) * int16(vec_A1(num_k));
    else  
        vec_final(num_k) = vec_d(num_k);
    end
end
% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

Hope it helps.